# Sitecore JSS Federated Authentication in Production Environment (Headless mode)

Tags: jss, federated-authentication

We are building a `DXP solution` for our customers that requires `Federated Authentication (via Azure AD)`. The solution is built on top of `Sitecore JSS` using `Angular`. The documentation related to `Federated Authentication` in `JSS` states:

*"This approach does not work in headless or connected modes, because it depends on browser requests directly to Sitecore."*

see: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/enable-sitecore-integrated-federated-authentication.html

On the other hand, the official documentation also states regarding performance considerations
*"Avoid running applications in integrated mode on Sitecore Content Delivery servers."*

see: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/190/sitecore-headless-development/optimizing-the-performance-of-jss-apps.html

My question is:

What is the officially supported and recommended setup to use `JSS` with `Federated Authentication` in production environments?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I have a `Sitecore JSS` website using `React` in production that also uses `Federated Authentication`. I did run into some issues, but it does work if you're using cookies.

I wrote a blogpost about the setup: http://www.jeroenbreuer.nl/blog/custom-identity-provider-in-sitecore/

Comment: Would be great to fine tune this answer with code from your blog post and refer blog post at the end so if blog does not exists anymore, this answer will be still relevant...

Comment: The code is also available on Gist so even if the blog does not exist anymore that will still be there: https://gist.github.com/jbreuer/ed69146f63aa1b20058092ab382ee0a7

Comment: Your answer is in another castle. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. I understand the "Your answer is in another castle." comment because I reference a blogpost. But I already give an answer before I add the blogpost. That is just there as extra proof to support my answer.